# Redux-Saga - watcher, takeEvery

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

Изучал `react-saga`, делал все по примеру из этого источник: https://hackernoon.com/redux-saga-tutorial-for-beginners-and-dog-lovers-aa69a17db645

Раньше работал с `react-thunk` и там в отдельном файле (`actionTypes.js`) прописывал все action types и брал из этого файла константы и подставлял в нужные места. 
Тут я заметил, что если в `takeEvery` подставлять переменную `API_CALL_REQUEST`, то ничего не работает, но если подставить `"API_CALL_REQUEST"` работает. Почему так?

actions/actionTypes.js

```
export const API_CALL_SUCCESS = "API_CALL_SUCCESS";
export const API_CALL_FAILURE = "API_CALL_FAILURE";
export const API_CALL_REQUEST = "API_CALL_REQIEST";
```

sagas/index.js

```
import { call, put, takeEvery } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import axios from 'axios';
import { 
    API_CALL_REQUEST, 
    API_CALL_SUCCESS, 
    API_CALL_FAILURE 
} from '../actions/actionTypes';

export function* watcherSaga() {
    yield takeEvery("API_CALL_REQUEST", workerSaga);
}

function fetchDog() {
    return axios({
        method: "GET",
        url: "https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random"
    });
}

function* workerSaga() {
    try {
        const response = yield call(fetchDog);
        const dog = response.data.message;
        yield put({ type: API_CALL_SUCCESS, data: dog });
    } catch (error) {
        yield put({ type: API_CALL_FAILURE, data: error });
    }
}
```

Если так:

```
export function* watcherSaga() {
    const test = "API_CALL_REQUEST";
    yield takeEvery(test, workerSaga);
}
```

то работает, но если так:

```
export function* watcherSaga() {
    const test = API_CALL_REQUEST;
    yield takeEvery(test, workerSaga);
}
```

снова нет. Что не так с константой `API_CALL_REQUEST`? С другими же константами из этого же файла никаких проблем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"API_CALL_REQUEST" !== "API_CALL_REQIEST"

Comment: как легко и изящно решается проблема)